# elasticsearch query is not working for numbers

Tags: elasticsearch

When I use the following statement I can get the result

```
GET project/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
        "contract_code": "202301"
      }
   }
}
```

[successful picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRJpH.png)

But the retrieval condition is four numbers and it fails

```
GET project/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
        "contract_code": "2023"
      }
   }
}
```

[fail picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3se3.png)

this is mapper setting

```
PUT /project/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "content": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
      "search_analyzer": "ik_smart"
    }
  }
}
```

Realize unlimited number length search

Comment: It would help if you can share the definition of the ik_max_word and ik_smart analyzers. Also you're sharing the mapping of the `content` field but your query is on the `contract_code` field.